# Publishing of multiple Angular apps to Cloudflare workers with wrangler

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm new to CF workers and the wrangler publish system, and I can find very little information around my requirements within online sources, perhaps my search query is wrong, so hoping I can find some help here.

I have an NX workspace, containing 2x apps. One app is deployed into the top-level worker, and the second one should be deployed to a sub-directory in the same worker, effectively create a parent-child structure, like the following:

```
example.com/ -> top-level app
example.com/site2/ -> child-level app
```

My issue is, I do not understand where and how to define, in `wrangler.toml`, the `/sub-directory/`. Should I have 2x separate worker-sites for these? I was under the impression that, I could just update the worker (`index.js`) file in my single worker-site to handle `/site2/` otherwise treat the request as standard?

All I would really like to know is, how can I specify that my publish should to the `/site2/` sub-directory, if at all possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to handle this. If your code / logic in the workers for the top-level vs child-level is completely different, I'd recommend using two separate workers. Then you can configure which "routes" each worker will run on -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/cli-wrangler/configuration

Worker 1 could be -

```
routes = ["example.com/"]
```

Worker 2 could be -

```
routes = ["example.com/site2/"]
```

Check this out for more details on how routing / matching behaves -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/routes#matching-behavior

The other way to do it would be to have a single worker, and inspect the incoming request to behave differently depending on whether the request is at the root, or at /site2/. I'd only recommend this if there are small differences between how the two sites should behave (e.g. swapping out a variable).

Comment: I tried the alternate approach, as I have a single build pipeline that builds the apps, so effectively wanted use two separate deploy tasks for each of the sites, doing the top-level first, and then secondly, after the first succeeds, the second task. Which didn't work. I'll try the separate workers and see if that is a better way to go. Thanks @David